# Powerpoint vba Effect Appear all BUT first line?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I import a list of questions from Word.  Then I run a macro to animate the text to Appear.

How do I turn off the first question?  Or how do I set all BUT THE FIRST LINE to appear?

```vb
Sub AnimateQuestions()
Dim AP As Presentation
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim oEff As Effect

Set AP = ActivePresentation
Dim Shp As Shape

Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set Shp = Sld.Shapes(2)
    With Sld
        Set oEff = .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shp, msoAnimEffectAppear, _
        msoAnimateTextByFirstLevel, msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
    End With
With Sld
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I figured it out.
Sld.TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Delete
Will delete the first occurrence after setting all of them.